# Passing a function as a variable and assigning it to an object still able to reference "self" in Lua

Tags: mobile, lua, coronasdk

So, I'm trying to write a function which accepts functions as its parameters and sets them as 'object' methods in Lua. Is there a specific syntax for this of which I'm not aware?

```
local function createObjectWithMethods(method1, method2)
    local object = {}
    object.meth1 = method1
    object:meth2 = method2 --this throws an error expecting parameters
    return object
end
```

Is there another way to go about this? I know that I could hardcode a method for the object, but this code needs to have functions passed as parameters, and some of those functions need to be able to reference self. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the passed-in methods without the automagic `self` syntax sugar.

That is you can't use:

```
function obj:meth1(arg1, arg2)
    -- code that uses self
end
```

(unless these functions are defined on some other object and being cross-applied to the new object).

Instead you need to write what the above is sugar for yourself.

```
function meth1(self, arg1, arg2)
    -- code that uses self
end
function meth2(self, arg1, arg2)
    -- code that uses self
end
```

Then you can just call the function normally and assign the functions normally.

```
local function createObjectWithMethods(method1, method2)
    local object = {}
    object.meth1 = method1
    object.meth2 = method2
    return object
end

createObjectWithMethods(meth1, meth2)
```

Comment: Well, that works. Thank you very much for the quick response.

Comment: The key here is that the `:` function creation syntax is just syntactic sugar for the version that includes `self` in the argument list and that the `obj:meth(...)` calling syntax is just sugar for `obj.meth(obj, ...)` syntax (with the exception that `obj` is only evaluated once).

Comment: It is actually straightforward to reference a method of a given object and make it a method in another object. So, for the `function obj:meth1` example at the beginning of this answer, just pass `obj.meth1`. No matter what syntax is used, you have to know if a function is a method or not when you call it.

Comment: @TomBlodget Correct, you can absolutely "steal" a method from one object and use it on another one. That was my aside about "cross-applied". My point was that you can't object-less-ly define a function using the sugar.